# 'All he wrote is novels ' or 'All he wrote are novels'?

Tags: verb-agreement

**'All he wrote is novels ' or 'All he wrote are novels'?**

I understand there is subject-verb agreement in English, but I always feel it should be 'All he wrote are novels'. Then does it become object-verb agreement? Now of course it's probably debatable whether we can call 'novels' the object of 'be' in the sentence since it's a predicate. What do the native speakers think about this? I'm not a native speaker of English.

Comment: Both sentences are wrong, since it's also in the past tense. It should be: *All he wrote* ***was*** *novels.* (But, in the present, it would be: *All he writes* ***is*** *novels.*

Comment: All he wrote (the sum total of his work) consists of a number of novels. If you want it to be plural you could say 'All his published works are novels.'

Comment: Thanks everyone! Yes. The tense is wrong here... So it seems you would prefer _All he wrote was novels_? I'm not sure what the speaker meant by "he wrote"; it was an example from a paper. Thank @KannE for your suggestions.

Comment: @JasonBassford I don't understand how the tense of a matrix clause could or even should be determined by that of a subordinate clause. I thought it was the other way around. I believe that if a matrix clause is in the past tense, a subordinate clause should often be in the past tense. In this case, I think you certainly can say _It's only novels that he wrote._ as well as _It was only novels that he wrote._ Then what's stopping you from saying _All he wrote is novels._?

Comment: In my opinion it's "All he wrote is novels", but "Novels are all he wrote".  The tense of "write" is irrelevant: "All he writes is novels", "Novels are all he writes".  (My wife agrees with me.)

Comment: @JK2 How can you say *All he wrote is novels?* If the writing was in the past, then he's no longer writing anything. I also *wouldn't* say *It **is** only novels that he wrote*, I would say *It **was** only novels that he wrote.*

Comment: @JasonBassford Firstly, the past form _wrote_ doesn't necessarily mean he's no longer writing anything. All it means is his act of writing happened in the past; there's no mention of his act of writing not happening in the present or future. Secondly, the present form _is_ has nothing to do with whether his act of writing happened in the past or it is still happening in the present or it will happen in the future. All it denotes is the statement (_All he wrote is novels._) is true regardless of time.

Comment: @JK2 I agree that in the particular case of reported speech (*she said the earth is round*) tenses can be mixed in this way, But that's a very specific syntactical form that describes something literal (that's what was said back then). But, that aside, I don't agree at all that this should happen or that (most) people would not simply be confused by it. Even if it can be argued as acceptable, I don't think should be done.

Comment: @JasonBassford You may have understood my last comment backward. Your example of reported speech only shows whether and when the past tense of a matrix clause affects the tense of a subordinate clause. The OP's example is a case where you're claiming that the past tense of a subordinate clause should affect the tense of the matrix clause. And I'm saying there's no such rule in English saying that the past tense of a subordinate clause should affect the tense of the matrix clause. It is not "argued", but I can find you hundreds of similar examples in Google News/Books, if I tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["When all you hear is fear and lies"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74072/when-all-you-hear-is-fear-and-lies)